# question about integral over compact set and bound

Tags: measure-theory, integration

Suppose $f(t)$ exists and is finite for a.e. $t \in [0,T]$. Then can I say that $\int_0^T f(t)h(t) \leq K\int_0^T |h(t)|$ for some constant $K$? I know nothing about whether $f$ is continuous, but since I know that $f$ is finite a.e. on a compact set ([0,T]) then I think I can do this, right? What if it's (0,T)? It doesn't matter.

Comment: No. For example, $f(x)=1/x$, $x\ne0$, $f(0)=0$ is finite everywhere in $[0,T]$. This $f$ furnishes a counterexample to your claim by taking $h$ to be a non-zero constant function.

Comment: Consider also $f(x)=1/\sqrt x$ (which is integrable) and functions of the form $h_n=f\cdot\chi_{[1/n,T]}$.